# How can I add a scroll on my JList? [JAVA]

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jlist

Ok, so here's the question. I have a JList, where the user is supposed to add some elements, and then the name of the element is displayed on a JList. I searched in all the web for adding a scroll on the JList but non of these worked. Can someone help me?
This is the code of the JList, in the method 'initialize()':

```
 list = new JList();
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getClickCount()==2) {
                    textFieldRagioneSociale.setText(ragionesociale.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldNomeAzienda.setText(nomeazienda.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldIndirizzo.setText(indirizzo.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldCAP.setText(CAP.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldLocalita.setText(localita.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldProvincia.setText(provincia.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                    textFieldPartitaIVA.setText(partitaiva.get(list.getSelectedIndex()));
                }
            }
        });
        frmCedamClienti.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        list.setBounds(10, 10, 155, 255);
        frmCedamClienti.getContentPane().add(list);
```

Comment: So, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds(...)!!!

Answer (score 2):

You put the JList inside a JScrollPane.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
...
```

Comment: Or simply `new JScrollPane( list );` And don't forget to add the scrollPane to the frame not the list.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. It doesn't show the list

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you should add the `JList<>()` to your `JScrollPane()`.
Simple way would be as below :

```
    JList list = new JList(new DefaultListModel<>());
```

Than place your list in `JScrollPane()` by :

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
```

Finally, add your `JScrollPane()` to contentPane of your `JFrame`, simply by :

```
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

And then, adding items to your `JList<>()` would look something like :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        ((DefaultListModel) list.getModel()).addElement(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Here you can find full code sample:

```
public TestFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 263, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JList list = new JList(new DefaultListModel<>());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 227, 239);

    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        ((DefaultListModel) list.getModel()).addElement(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) 1) The simple answer for add a JList (or any component) to a JScrollPane was given 20 minutes earlier. No need for duplicate answers. 2) The posted code uses a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, so any suggestion we make should show how to use Swing properly.